# Is there way to repeat particular pixels in css sprite working

Tags: html, css, css-sprites

[image]

see the images in that both gradients are repeating , i want to repeat only the orange gradient.  my css code:  `#header{background: url(images/background-spirit.png) repeat-x 0px -20px ;height: 50px;}`

[image: it's coming like this ,i want repeat only the orange gradient]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope..

It is not possible to repeat only part of a background image..

You will have to create two different images..

---

If you **absolutely have** to use a sprite, like the one you posted, you can ***stretch*** the background with the `background-size` property but you do not have very fine control..

for example the following will stretch the image so much that it will fill a 500px box

```
background-size:1000% 100%;
```

demo at http://jsfiddle.net/gaby/V62j6/

(*but for your use-case you should just create two different images*)

Comment: @SureshrangdePerumal, just updated answer with a workaround (*not suggested though..*)

Answer (score 2):

If your background is just using repeat-x and has a fixed height then could you put the blue gradient underneath the orange one?

[image: sprite]

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/bZ7W5/

Answer (score 0):

If you want just the orange, edit the image and remove blue:

[image]

Comment: i am using that blue gradient in other place

Comment: Its a sprite image, so I'm assuming this change would affect other elements using this same image.

Comment: In that case, you need to place the blue image BELOW the orange, so you can use it elsewhere.